# Duplicate key row when inserting in to recently truncated table

Tags: java, sql, prepared-statement

I have a table that is re-used daily. First, we clear it out. I've tried both:

```
BEGIN TRAN
DELETE FROM <tableName>
COMMIT
```

and

```
BEGIN TRAN
TRUNCATE TABLE <tableName>
COMMIT
```

These commit successfully and I can go look and the table is indeed row-less. Then in its own transaction, I go to insert all of today's data (using Prepared Statements in Java), and each and every row gives:

```
java.sql.SQLException: 
Cannot insert duplicate key row in object '<tableName>' with unique index '<index>'. 
The duplicate key value is (<column A>, <column B>, <column C>).
```

An index does exist on that table that is unique and non-clustered for A, B, C, but why is it considered duplicate data when the table itself is empty?

Comment: Still the table is empty but most probably you are inserting records that are duplicate as exception says.

Comment: Rare case - but sometimes you can have several tables with same name (but different schema/owner) in oracle/db2/mssql - so maybe you're clearing one table, but trying to write into another

Comment: Show your table definition.

Comment: @Lashane I do log out the name, and it seems to be the same. This is a good thought, though.

Comment: Try inserting a single row and view the table data. Then try adding a second and see if there are indeed duplicates.

Comment: Show the table definition *and* some sample data that is causing the problem.

Comment: Based on @rontornambe I tried doing this slowly with a small data-set (which should've been the first thing I tried). And I can do it manually; that is, I can insert something, delete it, and re-insert it. The problem is most certainly in the way my code is structured to do these and my high-level abstraction is causing an X-Y problem =( Sorry for troubling everyone!

Comment: I think you are iterating towards a solution. Check your abstractions and make some simple tests with them. Don't fret about troubling us, we would just ignore the comments if you were.

Comment: Aha, so it's something to do with bad data/error handling. I ran the program against a smaller, simpler data set and it runs cleanly, repeatedly. Now to find out what's different/why that behaves as such...

Comment: It's absolutely bad data. I have no idea why, but that environment's been exporting malformed data for weeks. I'm unsure why that's causing this program to find duplicate rows; possible some sort of race somewhere, or poorly handled exception. No good answer, but also no reason to keep pursuing this as our answer is just to get better data. How do I go about closing this? It seems this sort of answer is unsatisfactory, but there's not much motivation to keep talking/researching.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally tracked down what was happening here, thanks for some debugging help from the comments.

The issue was really in my strategy and transaction handling. I was trying to do two conflicting things:

- Executing first as a batch of ~1000 inserts, and if one failed switching to line-by-line
- Keeping one transaction for all of them.

The issue is that the first batch via `PreparedStatement` would actually succeed on some of them but throw a warning, then proceed to insert line-by-line, leading to duplicate data exceptions. This was harder to track because `DataTruncation` in a batch results in an `SQLException`, not a `SQLWarning`.

The solution was to move the transactions down to the two execution strategies.